# how to have access to object tree of trading view through a custom indicator?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

Can't have access to object tree of trading view through a custom indicator.

Hi.
My name is Abolfazl and I'm new to this script language.
I'm trying to create a custom indicator in trading view and i need to have access to the object tree of trading view.I was wondering if there is way doing that?
If there if no access is there a way that i get all drawings on the chart even thoes that are not writen by the indicator?

Answer (score 0):

User drawn objects are not accesible by pinescript. You need to do it programmatically.